# named_version is not deleted using ReconcileVersions function

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, enterprise-geodatabase, versioning

I am using below function to enter rows in table (branch versioning). My idea is to create a named version, submit the changes, reconcile and post it. After posting, named_version should be deleted.

```
arcpy.management.ReconcileVersions(
    input_database=working_layer_url,
    reconcile_mode="ALL_VERSIONS",
    target_version="sde.DEFAULT",
    edit_versions=version_name_full,
    acquire_locks="NO_LOCK_ACQUIRED",
    abort_if_conflicts="NO_ABORT",
    conflict_definition="BY_OBJECT",
    conflict_resolution="FAVOR_EDIT_VERSION",
    with_post="POST",
    with_delete="DELETE_VERSION",
    out_log=Reconcile_Versions_Log,
    proceed_if_conflicts_not_reviewed="PROCEED",
    reconcile_checkout_versions="DO_NOT_RECONCILE",
)
```

Above function works fine. However, above function does not delete the named version created by me. I get below error in the log file.

```
[6/13/2023 12:42:03 PM] Warning: Error deleting version xxxx.alta_test.[
    The version is currently in use. [xxxx.alta_test]
    ERROR: code:500, Extension not found, Internal server error.]
```

There is no documentation for this.

How can I do this?